# Issue with scrolling content on CollapsingToolbarLayout and NestedScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I'm having issues with the content frame content not scrolling with the use of CollapsingToolbarLayout. Is there a way that I han have a scrollable content pane with the CollapsingToolbarLayout? Tried using NestedScrollView with no luck

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/vehicle"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to start activityComponentInfo{ke.com.myapp.myapp/ke.com.myapp.myapp.activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Could not inflate Behavior subclass android.support.design.widget.AppBarLay‌​‌​out$ScrollingViewB‌​eh‌​avior
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
```

Comment: have you wrap them with `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`?

Comment: Try to change `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to `app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"`

Comment: And try to use `LinearLayout` instead of `FrameLayout` if above solution is not working. Let me know the update

Comment: yes it's wrapped around `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` and this is what i get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Invalid name: android.support.design.widget.AppBarLay‌​out$ScrollingViewBeh‌​avior`

Comment: i assume `app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLay‌​out$ScrollingViewBeh‌​avior"` was to be used as a property of `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`
Am using `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'`

Comment: changed from `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout` and still content not scrollable

Comment: Yes, you're right. Can you include your stack trace of ClassNotFoundException?

Comment: I've added it to the question because its too long. Wanted to capture everything

Comment: Make sure that you include both `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'` and `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'` then refresh your project. Make sure that you have the build tools 25.0.1 and android SDK 25 in your SDK manager. If not working, try to `File>Invalidate Caches/Restart`

Comment: same thing. I have a textfield that gets covered completely when the keyboard pops. Intended behavior is for the view to move up and the user to see what they are typing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129926/discussion-between-hendrawd-and-clifford-owino).